# How to print a static method in java that takes an int as parameter and returns a double

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty trying to print the result of the static method calcArea, which takes the int radius as parameter to calculate the area of a circle and returns the area.

Here's the code below  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class CircleArea {

    public int radius;

     public static void main(String[] args) {

          Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
          System.out.print("Enter the radius of the circle: ");

         int radius = input.nextInt();

          System.out.print("The area of the circle is:" + calcArea()); <-- ERROR HERE
     }

      public static double calcArea(int radius){          

          double  area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
          return area;          

      }
}
```

Comment: Why are you having 2 `radius` variable? Also, what is the exact error thrown to you?

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: The 1st one is the instance variable and the 2nd one is for the user to input the value of the radius to be stored to the instance variable, I think.

Comment: The Error Message says: method calcArea in class CircleArea cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function calcArea() takes the value of radius and then returns area. To do this, you need to pass an argument to calcArea(). So, your code should be like this:

```
    System.out.print("The area of the circle is:" + calcArea(radius));
```

The error you're getting clearly points out that you're missing an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `calcArea` needs a parameter passed in.  Probably `calcArea(radius)`.

Answer (score 0):

call method calcArea, you need give a parameter,Here are the correct example"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter the radius of the circle: ");
      int radius = input.nextInt();
      System.out.print("The area of the circle is:" + calcArea(radius));
 }
```